# QML Canvas - Why is the requestPaint() function not calling the paint?

Tags: javascript, qt, canvas, qml, qtquick2

**Reproducible example:**

Here I have drawn a beizer curve with QML canvas. The paint gets called only once even though I change the start and end values explicitly thus causing the signal to generate.

See the output too. ***Why the requestPaint() function doesn't call paint?***

***Test.qml***

```
import QtQuick 2.4

Canvas
{
    id: head; width: parent.width; height: parent.height

    property int    curveStartX: -1
    property int    curveStartY: -1
    property int    curveEndX: -1
    property int    curveEndY: -1

    Rectangle
    {
        id: startControlPoint
        x:  head.curveStartX; y: head.curveStartY; width: 15; height: 15; color: "red"; radius: 100

        onXChanged:  
        { 
           console.log("start called x1"); 
           head.requestPaint(); 
           console.log("start called x2")
        }

        onYChanged:  
        { 
           console.log("start called y1"); 
           head.requestPaint(); 
           console.log("start called y2")
        }
    }

    Rectangle
    {
        id: endControlPoint
        x: head.curveEndX; y: head.curveEndY; width: 15; height: 15; color: "red"; radius: 100
        onXChanged:  head.requestPaint ()
        onYChanged:  head.requestPaint ()
    }

    onPaint:
    {
        console.log ("Paint got called!")

        var ctx = getContext ("2d");
        ctx.beginPath ();
        ctx.clearRect (0, 0, head.height, head.width);
        ctx.fill ();

        ctx.strokeStyle = head.curveColor
        ctx.lineWidth   = 2;

        ctx.beginPath ();
        // start point of the curve.
        ctx.moveTo (head.curveStartX, head.curveStartY)
        ctx.bezierCurveTo (startControlPoint.x, startControlPoint.y,
                           endControlPoint.x, endControlPoint.y,
                           head.curveEndX, head.curveEndY);
        ctx.stroke ();
    }
}
```

***main.qml***

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window
{
    visible: true
    height: 500
    width: 500

    Test
    {
        id: what
    }

    Component.onCompleted:
    {
        what.curveStartX = 0
        what.curveStartY = 0

        what.curveEndX = 50
        what.curveEndY = 50
        /////////////////////////////////////////
        what.curveStartX = 10
        what.curveStartY = 10

        what.curveEndX = 60
        what.curveEndY = 60
    }
}
```

***Output:***

```
QML debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment.
qml: start called x1
qml: start called x2
qml: start called y1
qml: start called y2
qml: start called x1
qml: start called x2
qml: start called y1
qml: start called y2
qml: start called x1
qml: start called x2
qml: start called y1
qml: start called y2
qml: Paint got called!
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`requestPaint()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-canvas.html#requestPaint-method) only *requests* that the `Canvas` is repainted. If you take a look into [`QQuickCanvasItem::requestPaint()`](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtdeclarative.git/tree/src/quick/items/context2d/qquickcanvasitem.cpp#n905):

```
void QQuickCanvasItem::requestPaint()
{
    markDirty(d_func()->canvasWindow);
}
```

You can see that it calls [`QQuickCanvasItem::markDirty()`](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtdeclarative.git/tree/src/quick/items/context2d/qquickcanvasitem.cpp#n919):

```
void QQuickCanvasItem::markDirty(const QRectF& rect)
{
    Q_D(QQuickCanvasItem);
    if (!d->available)
        return;

    d->dirtyRect |= rect;

    polish();
}
```

Which in turn calls [`QQuickItem::polish()`](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtdeclarative.git/tree/src/quick/items/qquickitem.cpp#n4097):

```
void QQuickItem::polish()
{
    Q_D(QQuickItem);
    if (!d->polishScheduled) {
        d->polishScheduled = true;
        if (d->window) {
            QQuickWindowPrivate *p = QQuickWindowPrivate::get(d->window);
            bool maybeupdate = p->itemsToPolish.isEmpty();
            p->itemsToPolish.insert(this);
            if (maybeupdate) d->window->maybeUpdate();
        }
    }
}
```

So the `paint()` signal will be emitted whenever the scenegraph decides it is ready. The signal is emitted in [`QQuickCanvasItem::updatePolish()`](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtdeclarative.git/tree/src/quick/items/context2d/qquickcanvasitem.cpp#n681).

Comment: Exactly. Hence, simply do not implement your paint routine like that @TheIndependentAquarius. An approach would be to cache your points (e.g. with an array) and only call the repaint when a certain amount of such points are available. Requests are reduced and paint routine can complete correctly.